# Symfony 6.3 Service "security.access_token_handler.xxx": Parent definition "xxx" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6, symfony-security

I installed latest version of API platform which came with

- symfony/security-bundle:v6.3.8
- api-platform/core:v3.2.7

I am trying to build custom token handler according this this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/security/access_token.html#using-the-access-token-authenticator)

But I am getting following error: **Service "security.access_token_handler.api": Parent definition "Api\Security\AccessTokenHandler" does not exist**.

my token handler:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessToken\AccessTokenHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;

class AccessTokenHandler implements AccessTokenHandlerInterface
{
    public function getUserBadgeFrom(string $accessToken): UserBadge
    {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid credentials.');
    }
}
```

packages/security.yaml

```yaml
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            access_token:
                token_handler: Api\Security\AccessTokenHandler
```

Comment: It's App, not api in Api\Security\AccessTokenHandler

Comment: @FabienPapet thanks :), the error message was misleading